# Div with background image is not scaling with media queries

Tags: html, css, angularjs, media-queries

[page in quesstion](https://4waychess.com/#/game). I have a chess board where each cell is a div. I want the board to enlarge past certain min-widths using media queries, but it is not doing so.

The cells are generated by an ngFor loop. The black cells are class b, white cells are class w, filler cells outside the board (for spacing) are class e.
I am changing the padding and background-size to these divs in the media queries.

The media query is correctly moving my menu div when I rescale the browser. But it is not changing the background-image and padding to the e, b, and w divs.

The board can render when set to these new dimensions without media queries, so it seems as if the media queries are not working.

Here is the block of CSS with media queries:

```
.b{
  float: left;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a5a5a5;
  background-color:     #686868 ;
  background-size: 23.2px 23.2px;
padding: 10px;
}
.w{
  float: left;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a5a5a5;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
  background-size: 23.2px 23.2px;
padding: 10px;
}
.board{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
padding: 10px;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
  .rewind{
  padding: 10px;
  }
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .menu {
    order: 1;
    width: 25%;
  }
  .board {
    order: 0;
    width: 75%;
  }
  .e{
  background-size: 43.2px 43.2px;
padding: 20px;
  }
  .b{
  background-size: 43.2px 43.2px;
padding: 20px;
  }
  .w{
  background-size: 43.2px 43.2px;
padding: 20px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 420px) {

  .e{
  background-size: 33.2px 33.2px;
padding: 15px;
  }
  .b{
  background-size: 33.2px 33.2px;
padding: 15px;
  }
  .w{
  background-size: 33.2px 33.2px;
padding: 15px;
  }

}
```

Platform: All browsers, and uses Angular 1.5.8, Bootstrap 3.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your [CSS file](https://4waychess.com/main.css?41e47b24f2807e1ded2a) on the site (not in the code snippet above).

The CSS classes here need periods before the letters, not after.

The large version of the board looks good when this is changed. Does this solve the issue?

```
@media (min-width: 420px) {

  e.{
  background-size: 43.2px 43.2px;
padding: 20px;
  }
  b.{
  background-size: 43.2px 43.2px;
padding: 20px;
  }
  w.{
  background-size: 43.2px 43.2px;
padding: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I also had two mutually exclusive media queries.